# How implement onClick in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
final ArrayList<User> allBoxerData= new ArrayList<User>();

        allBoxerData.add(new User("Ramon \nDekkers",R.drawable.ramonfinalmej));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Sergio \nMartínez",R.drawable.sergiomej1));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Kiko \nMartínez",R.drawable.kikomej1));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Roberto \nSantos",R.drawable.robertofinal));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Dani \nCuevas",R.drawable.danimej1));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Roman \nVardanyan",R.drawable.romanfinal));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Ivan \nSalcines",R.drawable.ivanred));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Eva María \nNaranjo",R.drawable.evacuadrado));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Manzy \nPauwells",R.drawable.manzymej1));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Lara \nMartín",R.drawable.laramej1));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Antonio \nRodríguez",R.drawable.antoniomej));
        allBoxerData.add(new User("Katharina \nThanderz",R.drawable.katmej1));


        mylist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(),allBoxerData);


        mylist.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
        usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {
            //Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");
            if (position==1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Listttt View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

What is the problem? My application doesn't shows me my `Toast`. This code is in `extends Fragment`, and I have a `listview`. I need that when I click 1 item in my `listview` I go to other `Fragment`, but that does not work.

```
public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public List<User> allUsers;

    private Context context;

    /*************
     * Constructor
     *****************/
    public UsersAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<User> data) {


        context = ctx;
        allUsers = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return allUsers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        UserViewHolder holder = new UserViewHolder();

        final User user = allUsers.get(position);


        if(convertView==null)
        {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boxer_item, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (UserViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }




        holder.name.setText(user.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.icon);


        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              //  Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               if (user.getName().equals("Ramon \nDekkers")) {


                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Listttt View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // THIS WORKS BUT I NEED GO TO OTHER FRAGMENT. 

               }
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }


    private static class UserViewHolder {
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView name;

    }
}
```

Comment: Do u want to show toast only when user clicked the 1st positioned item?

Comment: How many items in the list?

Comment: No, I need go to other Fragment! Each item is one different Fragment. I have 12 items in my ListView

Comment: Toast is an example. But even Toast not works...

Comment: Does the toast inside the rowView#OnClickListener works?

Comment: Toast only works in Users adapter

Comment: This works: if (user.getName().equals("Ramon \nDekkers")) {


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Listttt View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // THIS WORKS BUT I NEED GO TO OTHER FRAGMENT. 

           }

Comment: The answer will be changed according to your updated question. Thats y I deleted my answer. Otherwise future visitors will mis understood the answer

Comment: please, open a chat and I tell you my situation, pls.

Comment: My objective is implement onClick in UserAdapter or in my fragment, because I need go to other Fragment when I click in 1 item in my ListView.

Comment: I think that is more easy implemnt onClick in UserAdapter because Toast WORKS, so... only I need how write "Intent to other fragment" but i don't know how do it... pls, open a chat or something, i lost a ot fo hours with this..

Comment: I have added another answer, check with that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Context like this.

```
private AppCompatActivity context;
```

Change your `UsersAdapter` constructor

```
public UsersAdapter(AppCompatActivity ctx, ArrayList<User> data) {
  //Your code
}
```

then in your click listener add the code to go to next fragment

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //  Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Fragment fragment = new NextFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //If you want to add to back stack
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I try this code yesterday. In extends BaseAdapter "getActivity()" not works, i need put "context.getSupportFrag..." and when i do this, android Studio say me that "cannot resolve the method getSupportFragmentManager()"

Comment: use `context` instead of getActivity() here.

Comment: Yes, I use ``context`` but inmediately I have an error  **cannot resolve the method getSupportFragmentManager()**

Comment: What kind of activity u are using? is it Activity or AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: None of those. I tell you before, i use **public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter**

Comment: I mean your activity. not adapter.

Comment: Method onClick is on adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127040/discussion-between-alex-chengalan-and-rf-mvs).

Comment: I have 2 .java , **public class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter** and **public class First_fragment extends Fragment** and in both ** I have method onClick** I need that in 1 of them works.

Comment: error: **required: android.app.FragmentManager** ; **found: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager** but i change to  android.app.FragmentManager but error is the same

Comment: use `context.getFragmentManager()` instead of `context.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: Fragment fragment = new NextFragment(); is the problem now, in "Next Fragment" I use my name of Fragment and error if I import it

Comment: Alex, if I change ``private AppCompatActivity context;`` in First_Fragment error in ``usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(),allBoxerData);
``

Comment: If you give me skype or face or mail, this problem posibly, would be 5 min... I say you more than 10 times... pls.

Comment: I already told you in chat that u must cast your getActivity() to MainActivity. Like this `usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter((MainActivity)getActivity(),allBoxerData);`

Comment: Ok, now, only 1 error, required: **android.app.Fragment** Found: **com.prueba.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx** when I use my fragment in line: _Fragment fragment = new NextFragment();_ . I use: _Ramon_dekkers fragment = new Ramon_dekkers();_

Comment: In "NextFragment" i must put my name of fragment no?

Comment: And when i use: Ramon_dekkers fragment = new Ramon_dekkers(); , line _fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, **fragment**);_  _fragment_ say me the same, required: android.app.Fragment Found: com.prueba.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx, solution? only 1 error!!! T.T

Comment: i found a solution in a fragment, dont worry, i put +1 for you, thanks

Comment: Bro you should refer the documents about Fragment in order to get the exact idea of what is fragments and fragments from support library.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Fragment fragment = new NextFragment();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getfragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(/*This needs to bee your fragment container*/, fragment);
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Error in fragmentManager

Comment: I think the proper code is `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()`

Comment: Can anyone help me with my code please? Can anyone give me a email and see my code ? is very important and i lost a lot of hours and more than 5 question about this in stackoverflow .... only is this,

Comment: exact. change fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); to getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

Comment: can you give me your skype or something to tell you my situation?

Comment: how can I send you a private message ?

Comment: i dont know, write your email, i copy this and after delete your message haha , ok?

Answer (score 0):

For the `mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`  to get called you have to remove that click listener.

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       if (user.getName().equals("Ramon \nDekkers")) {


            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Listttt View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // THIS WORKS BUT I NEED GO TO OTHER FRAGMENT. 

       }
    }
});
```

if you have an `RowClickListener` the touches will be handled there and not in the `ItemClickListener`

**UPDATE**

 and to open a fragment from fragment you need to

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Fragment fragment = new NextFragment();
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = context.getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_content_frame, fragment);
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); //If you want to add to back stack
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
     }
 });
```

When you need to get Support fragment manager call :

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager(); //If using fragments from support v4
```

or

```
FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getFragmentManager();
```

You are done.

Comment: gmetax, yes, i want click 1 item form my listview and go to fragment

Comment: I check your answer, wait, can you open a chat ?

Comment: I don't want to open a chat.

Comment: context.getSupport and myContext..... and all answers not works. Error. Anybody can open a chat with me or look all my code for help me? All the answers are the same, and none works.

Comment: Ok, dont worry, **close** this question,